# RavenDB does not invalidate cache when saving an object twice without loading

Tags: c#, .net, caching, ravendb

I'm testing a repository class `SettingRepository` which uses aggressive caching in this way:

```
private Settings Settings 
{
    get 
    {
        using (Session.Advanced.DocumentStore.AggressivelyCacheFor(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)))
        {
            return Session.Load<Settings>("settings/Settings") ?? new Settings
            {
                 SomeStringProperty = "DefaultValue"
            };
        }
    }
}

public string GetSomeStringProperty()
{
    return Settings.SomeStringProperty;
}
```

I have configured the document store to not use server notifications, but watch for `session.SaveChanges()` instead:

```
store.Conventions.ShouldAggressiveCacheTrackChanges = false;
store.Conventions.ShouldSaveChangesForceAggressiveCacheCheck = true;
```

I was testing the caching mechanism in the following way (NUnit):

```
// Arrange
var settings = new Settings
{
    SomeStringProperty = "SomeValue"
};
Session.Store(settings, "settings/Settings");
Session.SaveChanges();
RenewSession();

var initialRequests = Session.Advanced.NumberOfRequests;

// Act - Assert 1
var someStringProperty = _settingRepository.GetSomeStringProperty();
Assert.That(someStringProperty, Is.EqualTo("SomeValue"));
Assert.That(Session.Advanced.NumberOfRequests, Is.EqualTo(initialRequests + 1));

// Act - Assert 2
someStringProperty = _settingRepository.GetSomeStringProperty();
Assert.That(applicationName, Is.EqualTo("SomeValue"));
Assert.That(Session.Advanced.NumberOfRequests, Is.EqualTo(initialRequests + 1));

// Act - Assert 3
settings.SomeStringValue = "SomeValueModified";
Session.SaveChanges(); // DOES NOT INVALIDATE CACHE

settings = Session.Load<Settings>("settings/Settings");
settings.SomeStringValue = "SomeValueModified";
Session.SaveChanges(); // THIS DOES INVALIDATE CACHE

...
```

See the comments in code at the bottom. I have explicitly reload the `Settings` entity from the store before changes are tracked, while the object is passed by reference in the initial `Store`:

```
Session.Store(settings, "settings/Settings");
```

Is this by design? I would expect that change tracking is enabled from that point onwards.

Comment: This should work, on the face of it. Can you create a full failing test and send that to the support mailing list?

Comment: @AyendeRahien Sure, but what exactly do you need? If you remove the line that reloads the entity and add another assert to check for the modified value, you have your test. If you prefer that I send a full working `.csproj` let me know.

Comment: RavenDB has unit test helpers that can simplify writing full unit test. On this page there is a description with example of how RavenDB test can be written http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/server/troubleshooting/sending-support-ticket

Comment: @AyendeRahien I tried creating the test according to the docs, but it seems that aggressive caching is not effective for embedded document stores. Also I can't use `session.Advanced.NumberOfRequests` cause it stays at `0`. Could you please specify how to create a remote (possibly simulated) store easily that effectively uses HTTP requests?

Comment: NewRemoteDocumentStore() from RavenTEst

Comment: @Ayenda I did use that, it didn't work. I mean, it does work, but the tests as done in my question here do not fail, and also it seems there are no requests sent to the server.